# What does "chepa" mean in Nicaraguan Spanish?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales, definiciones, coloquialismos, nicaragua

What does the word *chepa* mean when used to refer to a person in Nicaraguan Spanish? What are some examples of how it is used?

Comment: As a curiosity, *chepa* in Colombia means "good luck".

Answer (score 2):

In Nicaragua we use the word *chepa* as slang for someone who's always getting into other's business to get gossip.
"No seás chepa, dejá de meterte en mis cosas."
"Don't be a chepa, stop getting in my stuff."

Comment: Is it used the same way as *atrevido* is?

Answer (score 1):

In Spain *chepa* means *joroba* (hump) or, according to RAE, *jorobado* (humpback).

It is believed by some that humps provide good luck, and so they rub lottery tickets on people's humps. I guess that's why in Colombia it means "good luck".

Answer (score 1):

> chepa.
>
> 1. f. coloq. Corcova, joroba.
> 2. f. Col. Suerte favorable.
> 3. m. jorobado. U. t. c. adj.

This is the actual definition for "chepa", but the most used in America is Hispanic *good luck* the second